# Reflection to get and use class properties

Tags: c#, class, reflection, gettype

I am trying to update a linked list from a datagridview using reflection so I don't have to write a line of code for each property.

The class:

```
public class clsUnderlying
{
    public int UnderlyingID { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public double RiskFreeRate { get; set; }
    public double DividendYield { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Expiry { get; set; }
}
```

One line of code per property works:

```
UdlyNode.Symbol = (string)GenericTable.Rows[IDX].Cells["Symbol"].Value;
UdlyNode.Expiry = (DateTime)GenericTable.Rows[IDX].Cells["Expiry"].Value;
etc.
```

But there are many classes and class properties, so I'd prefer to use a loop and  reflection, but I'm not sure how, and my attempt below has errors.

```
PropertyInfo[] classProps = typeof(GlobalVars.clsUnderlying).GetProperties(); 
foreach (var Prop in classProps)
{
    Type T = GetType(Prop); // no overload for method GetType
    UdlyNode.Prop.Name = Convert.T(GenericTable.Rows[IDX].Cells[Prop.Name].Value); // error on "Prop.Name" and "T.("
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions or links to further my understanding.

Comment: Do you have the list bound as `DataSource` to the `DataGridView` ?

Comment: The dgv datasource is a bindinglist which comes from the linkedlist, The linkedlist is not directly bound to the dgv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=DE-DE&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true). This way a changed value in the Grid will automatically be changed in your list:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = yourList;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

This would solve the case where you want to update values manually changed in the grid.

Comment: Thanks, its working - I didn't think there was such an easy solution.

Comment: @Zeus You`re welcome. I did neither until I stumbled myself over it. Before that I was looping manually and searching for values also.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection-based loop needs to use a different syntax:

- Property type is a property of [`PropertyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396),
- `Convert` has a [`ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype(v=vs.110).aspx) method that takes `System.Type`, and
- Property assignment needs to be done by calling `SetValue`

Therefore, your loop would look like this:

```
foreach (var p in classProps) {
    p.SetValue(
        UdlyNode
    ,   Convert.ChangeType(
            GenericTable.Rows[IDX].Cells[p.Name].Value
        ,   p.PropertyType
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks that really helps me understand more about reflection. Sorry - I can only accept one answer and Mong's answer is simpler, but I upvoted your reply and will use the code elsewhere.